# Why we need to select covariance structure for random effect in mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, covariance-matrix

As for normal regression model ( I mean non-mixed effect model. Only including fixed effect in the model), I don't need to determine the covariance structure separately. I just fit my model and have output generated in R for instance. But when a random effect is added, why we should determine the covariance structure before fit the mixed model( I only understand what is compound symmetry, variance components, unstructured, etc.). Are the covariance structures not fixed already by the random effects themselves included in the mixed model?

Comment: In regular OLS regression, you don't need to specify a covariance structure because you're assuming that every observation is independent and identically distributed, or at least the autoregressive nature of the data is so minimal that it's basically iid.

Comment: ... and thus in the linear normal (fixed-effects) model you do implicitly specify the covariance structure as the joint normal distribution will have a diagonal covariance matrix due to the independence assumption.